# How to display table columns as rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Current Table:

```
Questions  Response  Sol 25 A  Sol25B Sol25C Sol40A Sol40B
===========================================================
A           0          0        1       4     10      3
B           1          4        0       5     56      1
C           0          5        1       4     4       2
```

I need expected result as below using the Where condition `Question = x AND Response = Y`

Expected Output is:

```
Product   Col1  Col2   Col3   Total
===================================   
Sol25A    0      4      5      9
Sol25B    1      0      1      2
Sol25C    4      5      4      13
Sol40A    10     56     4      70
Sol40B    3      2      1      6
```

Can you please provide me the SQL query for this.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please show your attempt

Comment: Please, show your current code: what did you try and what was wrong with it?

Comment: Would the output always have 5 expected rows, or could there be more/less than this?

Comment: You said `I need expected result as below using the Where condition Question = x AND Response = Y` , but the expected output shown does not seems to be for one particular question and response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT product, col1, col2, col3, col1+col2+col3 AS total
FROM (
    SELECT product,
        SUM(CASE WHEN questions='A' THEN val END) AS col1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN questions='B' THEN val END) AS col2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN questions='C' THEN val END) AS col3
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM exp
        UNPIVOT (
            val FOR product IN (sol25a, sol25b, sol25c, sol40a, sol40b)
        ) AS unp
    ) s
    GROUP BY product
) b;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Pivot and UnPivot in SQL Serve.
you can find more information in below link:
Visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot

```
SELECT 'AverageCost' AS Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days,   
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]  
FROM  
(SELECT DaysToManufacture, StandardCost   
    FROM Production.Product) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
AVG(StandardCost)  
FOR DaysToManufacture IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])  
) AS PivotTable;
```